# Iterate through inherited classes and call their static methods

Tags: java, inheritance, static-methods

I want to iterate through some classes, that inherit from the same superclass.
They all have the same static method, but how can I call it?

I tried it like this, but that does not work:

```
public abstract class Tower {
    private static int text = 5;

    public static int getText() {
        return text;
    }
}

public class aTower extends Tower {
    private static int text = 10;

    public static int getText() {
        return text;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        LinkedList<Class<?extends Tower>> towers = new LinkedList<>();
        towers.add(aTower.class);

        for (int i = 0; i < towers.size(); i++) {
            towers.get(i).getText(); //Does not work
        }
    }
}
```

**Context**

I want to have a list of classes that inherit from Tower for calling static methods of them, for getting e.g. their texture. Is there any other way to do that?

**Edit:** The main goal is, that I will have many different Towerclasses in a list, and there should be a menu with every towerclass. To paint the menu, I want to get for example the texture, the name, etc. When you click on the menu entry, then you should get an object of the specific tower and you can build it somewhere. But I do not like the idea of having a list of more or less unused instances, and therefore I thought having a static method is the right solution.

Comment: Static methods belong to the class, not to class instances.  Therefore, you do not inherit static methods using the Java inheritance mechanism and the type system will not be able to guarantee that any given subclass has a particular static method.  One possible solution is to create an instance method that accesses and returns the value of the static field.

Comment: is your method must be static? overriding concept is not applicable for static methods.

Comment: @scottb Not exactly. You can't *override* the static methods, but you do inherit them, and all subclasses will have  `Tower.getText` as a visible method (i.e. `aTower.getText()`) if they don't declare one themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Java [Interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) though as already stated they wouldn't be static methods.

```
 public interface ITower {
   public String getText();
 }
```

from this point you define your tower objects that implement *ITower* and then inside *main*:

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String [] args) {
     List<ITower> towers = new LinkedList<>();

     // create your tower objects and add them to the list
     towers.add(new ATower());
     towers.add(new BTower());

     for (ITower iObj : towers) {
         iObj.getText();
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By converting your static method to an instance method, and using a static field within each subclass, you can get this to work:

```
public abstract class Tower {
    private static int text = 5;

    public int getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class aTower extends Tower {
    private static int text = 10;

    @Override public int getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        LinkedList<aTower> towers = new LinkedList<>();
        towers.add(new aTower());

        for (int i = 0; i < towers.size(); i++) {
            towers.get(i).getText(); 
        }
    }
}
```

In your original `main()` method, you created a `List` instance for `Class` objects.  I think you had really intended for this to contain `aTower` instances.  This is important because class `Class` will not have a `getText()` method.

Comment: *"you can get this to work"* ... when why won't your code compile?

Comment: Well, of course, there is the Java convention that does not allow defining two public classes within the same class file.

Comment: Well, then I would suggest to move each public class to his own file or remove the access modifiers, but test your code, please.

Answer (score -1):

Polymorphism doesn't work with static methods. Why do you want `getText()` to be static?

If you have a no-arg constructor in `Tower` you can use reflection to create an instance from a class name.

```
Class<Tower> towerClass = (Class<Tower>) Class.forName(classString);
Tower tower = towerClass.newInstance();
tower.staticMethod();
```

Comment: Comments should be comments, not answers.

Comment: No, actually.  The StackOverflow site rules expressly forbid answers as comments.

Comment: Clarification: 'comments' are questions or clarifications you make in the comment section under the question (or under other answers). Answers are posts that are supposed to directly answer the question, not ask for additional information.

Comment: Some users would like to post Answer as Comment if they find good answer in external links